# Issue with visualforce rerender

Tags: visualforce, rerender

I have a Visualforce page that displays a list of Account Location custom objects related to the Account object.

[image]

Each Account Location in the table contains a "Del" link.  Clicking on this link invokes code in the Controller class that deletes the Account Location object.  The link then re-renders the containing pageBlock as well as an outputPanel.  The rerender works fine up until I use the "Del" link to delete the last Account Location.  When I do that, the last Account Location object is deleted.  However, the rerender displays the table with the just deleted Account Location object.  When I look at the related list on the Account object, there are no Account Locations present, so I know the Account Location was deleted.

I've included a slimmed-down version of the actual code below.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can resolve this issue?

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountLocationSelectionController" title="Update Sites" id="pg">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
    </script>

    <script src="/soap/ajax/21.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/21.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validatestate(){
            var sMessage = document.getElementById('pg:idLocationMessage').innerHTML;
            if(sMessage!=''){
                console.log(sMessage);
            }
        }
        function confirmbeforedelete(){
            return confirm("Are you sure ?");
        }

        function canBeDeletedHandler(recordId,accountId){
            if(sforce.apex.execute("AccountLocationSelectionController","canBeDeleted",{rId:recordId,accId:accountId})
== 'true'){
                if(confirm("Are you sure ?")){
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
            else{
                alert('This site cannot be deleted because it has been selected on other RFPs.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <apex:pageMessages />

    <apex:outputpanel id="idLocationMessage">{!AccountLocationMessage}</apex:outputpanel>

    <apex:form id="theForm">

                <apex:pageBlock id="TablePanelAvail"
                        rendered="{!availableLocations.hasLocations}"
                        title="Available Locations">

            <apex:actionStatus id="TableUpdateStatusAvail">

                <!-- loading message -->

                <apex:facet name="start">
                    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="message infoM4">
                        <apex:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="messageTable" columnClasses="messageCell" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                            <apex:panelGroup >
                                <img class="loading-icon" src="/s.gif" />
                            </apex:panelGroup>
                            <apex:panelGroup >
                                <div class="messageText">Please wait...</div>
                            </apex:panelGroup>
                        </apex:panelGrid>
                    </apex:outputPanel>
                </apex:facet>

                <!-- Available Locations table -->
                <apex:facet name="stop">

                    <apex:pageblocktable value="{!availableLocations.AccountLocationList}" var="record"
                                         title="Total available account locations: {!availableLocations.totalAccountLocations}"
                        rendered="{!availableLocations.totalAccountLocations > 0}">

                        <!-- Selected -->
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="TablePanelAvailCbx" class="selectall" value="Selected"/>&nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold;">Action</span>

                            </apex:facet>

                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!record.selected}"/>&nbsp;

                            <!--oncomplete="validatestate();" -->
                            <apex:commandlink value="Del" onclick="if(!canBeDeletedHandler('{!record.loc.id}','{!accountId}')) return false;"
                                              action="{!doDelete}"
                                               oncomplete="validatestate();"
                                              rerender="idLocationMessage,TablePanelAvail"
                                              status="TableUpdateStatusAvail">
                                <apex:param name="rId" value="{!record.loc.id}" assignTo="{!recordId}"/>
                            </apex:commandlink>


                        </apex:column>

                        <apex:column value="{!record.loc.Name}" headerValue="Name" />

                        <apex:column value="{!record.loc.Id}" headerValue="Id" />

                    </apex:pageblocktable>

                </apex:facet>

            </apex:actionStatus>

        </apex:pageBlock>

        </apex:form>
         </apex:page>
```

Controller class:

```
global with sharing class AccountLocationSelectionController {
    public ID accountId {get; set;}
    public ID recordId {get; set;}
    public String AccountLocationMessage{get;set;}

    public AccountLocationMgr availableLocations {get; set;}

    public AccountLocationSelectionController() {

        accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('accountId');

        System.debug('accountId: ' + accountId);

         availableLocations = new AccountLocationMgr(accountId);
         System.debug('Available Site IDs = ' + availableLocations );

         System.debug('---- exiting ctor');
    }

    public PageReference doDelete() {
        System.debug('delete');

        Account_Location__c accountLocation = new Account_Location__c();
        accountLocation.Id = recordId;
        delete accountLocation;

        AccountLocationMessage ='Location deleted.';

        availableLocations.updateAccountLocationsList();

        System.debug('Available Site IDs = ' + availableLocations.accountLocationList );

        return null;
    }

    webService static boolean canBeDeleted(String rId,String accId) {
        boolean bRet = true;

        // Code removed for simplicity

        return bRet;
  }
}
```

Helper classes:

```
public class AccountLocationMgr {
    public Boolean hasLocations {get; private set;}

    public List<AccountLocationWrapper> accountLocationList {get; set;}

    public ID accountId {get; set;}

    public Integer totalAccountLocations {get; set;}

    public AccountLocationMgr ( String accountId )
    {
        this.accountId = accountId;

        updateAccountLocationsList();
    }

    public void updateAccountLocationsList() {
        this.accountLocationList = new List<AccountLocationWrapper>();

        String query = 'select ' +
            'Name, ' + 
            'AccountId__c ' + 
            'from Account_Location__c ' + 
            'where AccountId__c = :accountId';

        System.debug('----------- updateAccountLocationsList query:');
        System.debug(query);

        List<Account_Location__c> temp = Database.query(query);

        System.debug('temp.size = ' + temp.size());

        if ( (temp != null) && (!temp.isEmpty()) && (temp.size() > 0) ) {
            System.debug('Total account locations found for this Account = ' + accountLocationList.size());
            System.debug('temp total: ' + temp.size());
            this.hasLocations = true;
            for(Account_Location__c record : temp)
            {
                 this.accountLocationList.add(new AccountLocationWrapper(record, false));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.debug('No available locations found');
            this.hasLocations = false;
        }

        String totAvailLocnQuery = 'select count() from Account_Location__c ' +
                'where AccountId__c = :accountId ';
        totalAccountLocations = database.countQuery(totAvailLocnQuery);

    }
}

public class AccountLocationWrapper {
    public Account_Location__c loc { get; private set; }
    public Boolean selected { get; set; }

    public AccountLocationWrapper(Account_Location__c loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
        this.selected = false;
    }

    public AccountLocationWrapper(Account_Location__c loc, boolean selected) {
        this.loc = loc;
        this.selected = selected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try wrapping your pageBlockTable in an outputPanel?

Something like: 
 `<apex:outputPanel id="TablePanelAvail2">`

just before the `<apex:pageblocktable>` ?

and rerender the new outputPanel using the id `TablePanelAvail2` ?